# React-Admin: How do I call two endpoints simultaneously from one click event within a <form>

Tags: javascript, react-admin

So I have a `form` that contains the data about two tables on the backend:

- table **zone**, and
- table **area**

Normally, the `update` method in `react-admin` is just straight forward, but in this case not really.
So I have taken the data from the `zone` and `area` tables and put it in one form.

I also altered the `saveButton` to tweak the form `values` before submitting the form according to this [react-admin documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.9/Actions.html) so in this way values are in correct form before submitting.

**The challenge is that...**
When I click the button somehow in `onClick`, I would need to execute the `update` on 2 endpoints with 2 `update` calls to `dataProvider`. I was thinking to use `redux-saga` for this case, but didn't have luck yet.

Any ideas, hints, or code examples are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives are possible here:

- Call the two `dataProvider.updates` within a single click. Alternatively, you can `fetch()` directly for greater flexibility. (You might want to make use of `React.useCallback` and `async` for better performance)

```js
export const SaveButton = ({
  basePath = '',
  label = 'Save',
  record,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    if (record !== undefined) {
      // first call -> Zone
      async () => await dataProvider.update(...);
      // Second call -> Area
      async() => await dataProvider.update(...);
    }
  };
  return <Button label={label} onClick={handleClick} {...rest} />;
};
```

- Declare two functions to call each call `dataProvider.update` separately.
  This would give you flexibility if you intend to do the same calls once any other `clickEvent` is triggered within that same `component`

```js
export const SaveButton = ({
  basePath = '',
  label = 'Save',
  record,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    if (record !== undefined) {
      // first call -> Zone
      handleZoneCall();
      // second call -> Area
      handleAreaCall();   
    }
  };

  const handleZoneCall = async () => await dataProvider.update(...);
  const handleAreaCall = async() => await dataProvider.update(...);

  return <Button label={label} onClick={handleClick} {...rest} />;
};
```

One of the above should get you going...